# The ultimate emoji encoding scheme

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8, utf8mb4

This is my environment: Client -> iOS App, Server ->PHP and MySQL.

The data from client to server is done via HTTP POST.

The data from server to client is done with json.

I would like to add support for emojis or any utf8mb4 character in general. I'm looking for the right way for dealing with this under my scenario.

My questions are the following:

1. Does POST allow utf8mb4, or should I convert the data in the client to plain utf8?
2. If my DB has collation and character set utf8mb4, does it mean I should be able to store 'raw' emojis?
3. Should I try to work in the DB with utf8mb4 or is it safer/better/more supported to work in utf8 and encode symbols? If so, which encoding method should I use so that it works flawlessly in Objective-C and PHP (and java for the future android version)?

Right now I have the DB with utf8mb4 but I get errors when trying to store a raw emoji. On the other hand, I can store non-utf8 symbols such `¿` or `á`.

When I retrieve this symbols in PHP I first need to execute `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` (if I get them in utf8mb4 the `json_decode` function doesn't work), then such symbols are encoded (e.g., `¿` is encoded to `\u00bf`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQL's `utf8` charset is *not actually UTF-8*, it's a subset of UTF-8 only supporting the basic plane (characters up to U+FFFF). Most emoji use code points higher than U+FFFF. MySQL's `utf8mb4` is *actual UTF-8* which can encode all those code points. Outside of MySQL there's no such thing as "utf8mb4", there's just UTF-8. So:

> Does POST allow utf8mb4, or should I convert the data in the client to plain utf8?

Again, no such thing as "utf8mb4". HTTP POST requests support any raw bytes, if your client sends UTF-8 encoded data you're fine.

> If my DB has collation and character set utf8mb4, does it mean I should be able to store 'raw' emojis?

Yes.

> Should I try to work in the DB with utf8mb4 or is it safer/better/more supported to work in utf8 and encode symbols?

God no, use raw UTF-8 (`utf8mb4`) for all that is holy.

> When I retrieve this symbols in PHP I first need to execute `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`

Well, there's your problem; channeling your data through MySQL's `utf8` charset will discard any characters above U+FFFF. Use `utf8mb4` all the way through MySQL.

> if I get them in utf8mb4 the json_decode function doesn't work

You'll have to specify what that means exactly. PHP's JSON functions should be able to handle any Unicode code point just fine, as long as it's valid UTF-8:

```
echo json_encode('');
"\ud83d\ude00"

echo json_decode('"\ud83d\ude00"');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think my _real_ problem has to do with the DB configuration. By now I'm using a shared host, so I can't fully change from utf8 to utf8mb4. For instance, the only MySQL variables I'm able to change to utf8mb4 are `character_set_database` and `collation_database`, but the remaining (`character_set_client`, `character_set_connection`, `character_set_results`, `character_set_server`, `character_set_system`, `collation_connection` and `collation_server`) are still in utf8. I guess this is a gameover until I have access to my.cnf?

Comment: You should be able to choose your charset when connecting to the database, in your PHP code. No need to futz around with my.cnf at all.

Comment: The thing is: with `ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, and with `CREATE TABLE 'example' (
 'text' varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci` then if I run (from phpmyadmin) `INSERT INTO 'mydb'.'example' ('text') VALUES ('');` I get two warnings (`Invalid utf8 character string` and `Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80'`) and the stored data is just `????`.

Comment: The solution for me is use base64_encode to encode the text before save to DB. And decode the value when you going to use it.

Comment: @WeiJing I think this is the best solution!

Answer (score 4):

Use utf8mb4 throughout MySQL:

- `SET NAMES utf8mb4`
- Declare the table/columns `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`
- Emoji and certain Chinese characters will work in utf8mb4, but not in MySQL's utf8.

Use UTF-8 throughout other things:

- HTML:

`¿` or `á` are (or at least can be) encoded in utf8 (utf8mb4)