# Emoji character () is not working with utf8mb4_bin in MySQL version 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, utf, utf8mb4

I am trying to save emoji symbol to database record but each time it's not saving properly. 
I've referred this [How to store Emoji Character in My SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database) but still not working.
As per solution on above question, I tried to change the character set from utf8 to utf8mb4 and collation from utf8mb4_bin. 
I tried everything like resetting to default and then changing it in the database table. I tried utf8mb4_unicode_ci, utf8_unicode_ci and utf8mb4_bin but it's not working. 
I am using MySQL 5.6 version. And I am changing the collation with below query

```
alter table `users` convert to character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_bin;
```

The above code is working fine, it's changing the UTF type in database. But emoji is not saving properly it's saving as question marks (????)

**Below is my database table structure example:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'System generated id used for uniqueness',
  `introduction` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `other_details` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,    
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=41213 ;
```

**To save emoji using below PHP code:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$strWithEmoji = "";
$fullContent = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'
               + $strWithEmoji;
$this->save($fullContent); // Function for saving into database
```

I don't know exact how many bytes are storing but I am trying to save only 
this emoji character "" and it's storing it as 4 question marks (????).

I tried all solutions from below links, but didn't worked for me:
[How to store Emoji Character in My SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database)

[UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

[The ultimate emoji encoding scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637105/the-ultimate-emoji-encoding-scheme)

Comment: @Liam I tried all solution which is already asked, but it's not working

Comment: You've added pretty much nothing from your original question 2 days ago. Please don't ask the same question multiple times. It's not working isn't a question.

Comment: @Liam The question is deleted

Comment: Deleting the duplicate isn't going to help here. In fact it's making it look worse... There was a reason that that question was flagged (by a moderator) as duplicate of other questions. BTW people who can vote to close this can see the question even if you've deleted it.

Comment: @Liam I've specified all things which were not implemented in the previous question and it didn't help me. This is something another case I am trying to explain, then please specify how it is a duplicate.

Comment: Please provide exact bytes that are tried to be stored, and exact bytes actually stored. Also provide actual `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in the question. Also, remove all frameworks/3rd party libraries from your question and provide a php+pdo/mysqli only code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @zerkms Updated the question, I don't exact bytes, I am trying to save only single emoji character that I've mentioned in the question title. Thanks.

Comment: Also remove laravel or whatever you have and only run php+pdo/mysqli. That way you will isolate the problem. Then make sure that your file that is only php+pdo is in utf8 encoding and your pdo connection is also utf8.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think the problem is with PHP code because the code is working fine on localhost machine but for only live servers the issue is occurring.

Comment: @KRY what kind of help you are seeking for if you don't want to isolate the problem yourself? "I don't think" --- good. What do you suggest then?

Comment: @zerkms The code is working on my local machines but not working on live servers so clearly it's problem of MySQL, only I am not capturing what problem is there with MySQL and I've already updated the PHP code in question.

Comment: @KRY "so clearly it's problem of MySQL" --- good, if it's clear for you - you probably should know the answer. Otherwise, I'm not sure what that statement is based on. If you're not willing to properly isolate the problem - I'm not sure I'm ready to play the guessing game. Good luck then :-) "and I've already updated the PHP code in question." --- you have not. Isolation implies you don't have any frameworks or other 3rd party dependencies, just php+pdo (that I could run by myself on my local machine as-is), nothing else.

Comment: @zerkms Why don't you try other questions?

Comment: @KRY well, I wanted to help you isolate the problem, and when it's isolated if it still persists - I wanted to reproduce it locally to help you identify your problem. But you decided that you don't need my help. Well, after 8 hours did you make any progress? Do you still think the strategy you've chosen is efficient?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *connection* needs to specify `utf8mb4` to MySQL.  What is under the covers in `DOMDocument`?

is hex `F09F9880`, which should work in a column of `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` with any `utf8mb4_*` collation.

And here is another link:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

If all else fails, execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4` from PHP after establishing a connection.